# EntityFramework NuGet Package Won't Install

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, entity-framework-5, failed-installation

When I try to install EntityFramework though NuGet, I get the following:

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253898&clcid=0x409. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Unexpected end tag. Line 46, position 3.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Unexpected end tag. Line 46, position 3.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

This happens with older versions of EntityFramework as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to build and execute your application before installing entityframework. What I am guessing is there could be an error in web.config or some other file that has an unexpected end tag. Another thing would be to try installing it on a different project and if you still see the issue?
For example, when I tried to install it on a project with malformed  web.config I get the following error:
install-package entityframework
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253898&clcid=0x409. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 12, position 5.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 12, position 5.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package entityframework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: The project builds fine, so I'm not sure what's wrong. I started a new project and was able to install it, though, so I'll just merge the files.

Comment: After double-checking the web.config file, I saw that there was an additional </configuration> tag at the end, so your answer was spot-on. I'm surprised it was able to build without mentioning any warnings.